# How to store fiscal year (eg. 2017-2020) in mysql?

Tags: python, mysql, csv

I have data in CSV, in which one column is for fiscal year. 
eg. 2017 - 2019 .
Please specify how to form the CREATE TABLE query and INSERT query with the Fiscal Year as field.

Comment: If it is a range of years, I would store it as 2 separate 4 digit numbers.  This allows it to be used as part of a search a lot easier than holding it as a single field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since it seems like range of years for fiscal postion. I would suggest to use **two Integer field** to store data.
and

> and years will be in 4 numbers so use **Type SMALLINT**   this way you **use half of the storage space then INT field**.